# Prolog - Turning a list into a list of clauses

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to use meta programming and DCGs to turn a list into a list of clauses using Prolog. For example, I would like to turn [a, man, is, a, human] into [ (human(X) :- man(X)) ]

I figured that I could use =.. for composing terms from a list of their
constituent parts. For example, the call `Term =.. [f,a,b,c]` will bind Term to `f(a,b,c)`.

My problem is trying to combine this using DCGs. So far, I have used DCGs to check whether a sentence is of a valid form:

```
 %% syllogism( +S )
  % Holds if the sentence S is one of four syllogisms

  % a B is a C
  syllogism  --> article, subject, is_, (article ; [] ), subject .

  % some B is a C 
  syllogism  --> some, subject, is_, (article ; [] ), subject .

  % no B is a C
  syllogism  --> no, subject, is_, (article ; [] ), subject .

  % some B is not a C
  syllogism  --> some, subject, is_, not, (article ; [] ), subject .

  subject   --> [X] .
  some      --> [some] .
  is_       --> [is] .
  article   --> [a] .
  article   --> [every] .
  not       --> [not] .
  no        --> [no] .
```

However I am trying to modify this so that I can produce a list of clauses whilst still relying on DCGs.

EDIT:
Basically what I am trying to achieve is take a list L and produce a list of clauses:
[a, man, is, a, human] should produce [man(X) :- human(X)]

Similarly: [no, B, is, a, C] should produce [ (false :- B(X),C(X)) ]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Most of the time it is **not** advisable to use `(=..)/2` directly in the program. Instead you can give concrete structures.

Comment: The rule `subject --> [X].` means anything can be a subject. Is this intended?

Comment: Metaprogramming is exactly this case where using `=..` is necessary.

Comment: OK, thanks. How would I best go about using a DCG and =..? I understand that (.e.g.) p(X, Y) --> q(X), r(X, Y), s(Y).
translates into:
p(X, Y, Input, Output):-
    q(X, Input, Out1),
    r(X, Y, Out1, Out2),
    s(Y, Out2, Output).

However how would I assign something to the output?

Comment: @false: no, not really. What I am trying to express are these rules:
a B is a C =====> [ (C(X) :- B(X)) ]
some B is a C =====>  [ (B( some(B,C) ) :- true)
 some B is not a C =====> [ (B( some(B,not(C)) ):- true), (false :- C( some(B,not(C)) )) ]

i.e.
[a man is a human] =====> [ (human(X) :- man(X)) ]
etc

Comment: You could add an argument for that name. it does not make sense to keep it too general.

Comment: @user1796218 You need to state your facts first, then you can have your arguings. If you want to say a man is a human, first you must define men: "men(X) :- member(X, [men1, men2, men3]).", then, you state that every man is human, as "human(X) :- men(X).", and so you'll be able to ask "human(men1).", and receive your valid answer.

Comment: @Rubens: Yes, but that's not the way I want to do it :)

Comment: I want something along the lines of:

 syllogism( C )  --> article, subject( L1 ), is_, (article ; [] ), subject( L2 ), append( L1, L2, C ) .

  subject( [L] ) --> L =.. [X, Y], ground( X ) .
  some          --> [some] .
  is_           --> [is] .
  article       --> [a] .
  article       --> [every] .
  not           --> [not] .
  no            --> [no] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are going to need a meta-interpreter http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/meta_interpret.html

Ultimately all problems in Prolog come down to using the right kind of meta-interpreter.